# To include maven in dockerfile or not?

Tags: java, docker, maven, dockerfile

I have this working simple dockerfile.
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
WORKDIR /data
COPY target/*.jar, myapp.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar",myapp.jar]

I build my jar using maven either locally or in a pipeline then use that .jar here. I've seen many examples installing maven in the dockerfile instead of doing the build before. Doesnt that just make the image larger? Is there a benefit of doing that?

Comment: Well the benefit is you do not need to build the jar yourself?

Comment: You can use multi-stage images rather than one large image with all the tools... You can also **not** write a Dockerfile at all since SpringBoot 2.3 can automatically generate an image for you

Comment: I have a problem right now because to build a spring-boot application with maven in a Dockerfile I need to add also the related database and it must be up and running in order to work. Since I don't know exactly how to solve that I think I will just use the jar instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually I have a CICD server which I use for building my jar file and then I generate a docker image using it. Build a jar consumes resources and doing it when you're running your docker container can take longer depending on your configuration. In a normal CICD strategy, build and deploy are different steps. I also believe your docker image should be as lean as possible.

That's my opinion.

I hope I could help you somehow.

Comment: Thanks, thats what I was thinking as well. This is my first time using docker so I didnt want to miss something

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for Multi-stage builds.
Example of multistage Dockerfile:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM golang:1.16
WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/alexellis/href-counter/
RUN go get -d -v golang.org/x/net/html  
COPY app.go ./
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -installsuffix cgo -o app .

FROM alpine:latest  
RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates
WORKDIR /root/
COPY --from=0 /go/src/github.com/alexellis/href-counter/app ./
CMD ["./app"]
```

Notice the `COPY --from=0 ...`  line, it's copying the result of the build that happens in the first container to the second.
These mutistage builds are good idea for builds that need to install their own tools in specific versions.
Example taken from https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/